# Detect mobile Chrome on iOS

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, mobile

I need to detect mobile devices and I'm using this code, as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device-in-jquery) question.

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
 // some code..
}
```

However, it no longer detects Chrome on my iPad. How can mobile Chrome be detected now?

Comment: The reason that isn't working is because you don't have the exact user agent. So find your ipad chrome user agent and add it. check this link: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/user-agent

Comment: There is only section for chrome on iPhone, but not for ipad

Comment: I didn't see it say only for iPhone. iOS is the same of both devices.

Comment: so what should i use for detection string then?

Comment: Ah it does say iphone. so it may not work.. but what you could do is write some javascript to console log / alert the user agent when you go to it and see what it says when you use your ipad. then add it to you catch. But whats the goal here to know they are using an ipad or just a mobile device? because you could do what they call feature detection on the tap event.

Comment: only need to detect mobile

Comment: Have you tried adding `CriOS`?